# Getting 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map' even when I'm not casting any Long

Tags: android, firebase, casting, firebase-realtime-database, classcastexception

I'm trying to retrieve some data from `Firebase` using `addChildEventListener()` like this (code is in a `Service`):

```
    aReference.child(requestID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                // error on the line below
                Map<String, String> nUser = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                userNameAU = nUser.get("uName");
                Log.d("uName", userNameAU);
            }
            ...
            ...
});
```

but I'm getting this runtime error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map`.

As you can see, I'm not even trying to cast it any `Long` here, then why am I getting this error? The same code works fine in another activity.

Comment: It's the other way around: `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is returning a `Long` and you're trying to cast it to a `Map`.

Comment: Return value is long not map

Comment: @TedHopp but the same code works in another activity and both are retrieving data from same reference!

Comment: All I can suggest is that you store `dataSnapshot.getValue()` in an `Object` reference and then test its type, printing a diagnostic if it's not what you expect. Also, use a debugger to make sure that the `DataSnapshot` is exactly the same object. It's hard to believe that `getValue()` would return different object types on different calls for the same `DataSnapshot` object.

Comment: @TedHopp I carried out a diagnostic and here is the problem coming up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41294838/6144372 It's weird! Please check out.

Comment: @HammadNasir: don't open a new question for the same problem. This question lacks the minimal information needed to solve it, your other question also is incomplete.