# Firebase reference retrieving different values on calls in two different activities

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving some data from `Firebase` database using reference `aReference.child(rID).addChildEventListener()`, like this in `MainActivity`:

```
aReference.child(rID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                Log.d("dataSnapshot1", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            ...
            ...
});
```

and like this in `MyService`:

```
aReference.child(rID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                Log.d("dataSnapshot2", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            ...
            ...
});
```

though the reference is exactly same in both activities/service, `dataSnapshot1` is printing out this:

```
D/dataSnapshot: {currentLng=***, playerPicUrl=***, currentLat=***, poster=poster, playerName= Hammad Nasir}
D/dataSnapshot: {currentLng=***, playerPicUrl=***, currentLat=***, playerName=Mark}
D/dataSnapshot: {currentLng=***, playerPicUrl=***, currentLat=***, playerName=Elon Musk}
D/dataSnapshot: 1
```

and `dataSnapshot2` is printing out only:

```
D/dataSnapshot: 1
```

What is happening here? What's going wrong?

Comment: Given [your previous problem with a data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294540/getting-java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-long-cannot-be-cast-to-java-uti) it seems *very* likely that `aReference` is pointing to a different location in the activity and in the service.

Comment: Please show the code getting or intializing `aReference`.